# changing map values in groovy doesn't work

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I am using Groovy version 2.1.0. I am trying to read values from a map and update another map.

```
a = ["key1":"" ,"key2":""]
b = ["key1": "10", "key3":"99" ]
for (i in b){
 if( i.key in a)
   a.(i.key) = i.value
}
def key2 = "key2"
a.key2 = "value2"
println a.get("key2")
println "value returned is :" + a.get("key1") + ":"
```

This results in o/p

`value2
value returned is ::`

But if the map 'a' doesn't contain empty string as values, then it works fine as expected.

```
a = ["key1":"7" ,"key2":""]
b = ["key1": "10", "key3":"99" ]
for (i in b){
 if( i.key in a)
   a.(i.key) = i.value
}
a."key2" = "value2"
println a.get("key2")
println "value returned is :" + a.get("key1") + ":"
```

This results in o/p

`value2
value returned is :10:`

I want to update the empty map with values, like in the first scenario. Where am I getting it wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
if( i.key in a)
   a.(i.key) = i.value
```

To:

```
if( i.key in a.keySet())
   a.(i.key) = i.value
```

Answer (score 2):

As Opal says, it's the `if` that's causing difficulties...

```
if( i.key in a)
```

Will fail if the key is not in the map, OR the value equates to Groovy False

You could do:

```
a = ["key1":"" ,"key2":""]
b = ["key1": "10", "key3":"99" ]

a = (a+b).findAll { k, v -> k in a.keySet() }

def key2 = "key2"
a[ key2 ] = "value2"

println a.key2
println "value returned is : $a.key1 :"
```

(be careful, your `key2` bit wasn't doing what I believe you expected (it worked as your `key2` var name was the same as its value)